# Jquery - loop through each button to show the hidden div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have six boxes with six buttons, and I want to display a separate hidden div attached to each of the boxes when I hover each individual button. As you can see, I've done it for the first box (right now, with all buttons attached to it), but I want to know the ideal/correct way to loop over each individual button, to display the corresponding hidden div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hiddenOne, .hiddenTwo, .hiddenThree, .hiddenFour, .hiddenFive, .hiddenSix").hide();
  $(".button").each(function(index) {
    $(".button").hover(function() {
      $(".hiddenOne").fadeIn();
    });
    $(".hiddenOne").mouseleave(function() {
      $(".hiddenOne").fadeOut();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.centerThis {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.center2 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  /* establish flex container */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* enable flex items to wrap */
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.button {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.buttonTwo {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.buttonThree {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.buttonFour {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.buttonFive {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.buttonSix {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.white {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.hiddenOne {
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.hiddenTwo {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.hiddenThree {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.hiddenFour {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.hiddenFive {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.hiddenSix {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.itemWithin {
  flex: 0 35%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.itemWithin2 {
  flex: 0 35%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.itemWithin3 {
  flex: 0 35%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.itemWithin4 {
  flex: 0 35%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.itemWithin5 {
  flex: 0 35%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.itemWithin6 {
  flex: 0 35%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="itemWithin">
    <div class="hiddenOne">
      <h2 class="center2">Mining & Resources</h2>
      <p class="white">
        Here are the details when view more is hovered
      </p>
    </div>

    <h2 class="centerThis">Mining & Resources</h2>
    <button class="button">View More</button>
  </div>

  <div class="itemWithin2">
    <div class="hiddenTwo">
      <h2 class="center2">Defence</h2>
    </div>
    <h2 class="centerThis">Defence</h2>
    <button class="button">View More</button>

  </div>

  <div class="itemWithin3">
    <h2 class="centerThis">Energy & Water</h2>
    <button class="button">View More</button>

  </div>

  <div class="itemWithin4">
    <h2 class="centerThis">Public & Private Infrastucture</h2>
    <button class="button">View More</button>
  </div>

  <div class="itemWithin5">
    <h2 class="centerThis">Commercial & Residential Building</h2>
    <button class="button">View More</button>
  </div>

  <div class="itemWithin6">
    <h2 class="centerThis">Industrial Manufacturing</h2>
    <button class="button">View More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How certain are you that jQuery is the best way to achieve this affect and not just CSS?

Comment: I am working on a jquery solution, stand by

Comment: How are you meant to click the button if it's covered by the hidden div?

Comment: The button isn't part of the hidden Div. @AlexanderNied, It could be possible to do this through CSS, but the rest of the site is using JQuery for basic animations as well, so this is for consistency and structural reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".hiddenOne").hide();

        $(".button").hover(function () {
            $(this).parent().find('.hiddenOne').fadeIn();
        })

        $(".hiddenOne").mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        })
    });
```

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .centerThis {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .center2 {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .container {
        padding-top: 50px;
        display: flex;
        /* establish flex container */
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        /* enable flex items to wrap */
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .button {
        background: red;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .white {
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }

    .hiddenOne {
        height: 300px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .itemWithin {
        flex: 0 35%;
        height: 300px;
        margin-bottom: 2%;
        background-color: grey;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="itemWithin">
        <div class="hiddenOne">
            <h2 class="center2">Mining & Resources</h2>
            <p class="white">
                Here are the details when view more is hovered
            </p>
        </div>

        <h2 class="centerThis">Mining & Resources</h2>
        <button class="button">View More</button>
    </div>

    <div class="itemWithin">
        <div class="hiddenOne">
            <h2 class="center2">Mining & Resources</h2>
            <p class="white">
                Here are the details when view more is hovered
            </p>
        </div>

        <h2 class="centerThis">Mining & Resources</h2>
        <button class="button">View More</button>
    </div>
</div>
```